# 9Patch on different Android API level

Tags: android, colors, background, android-edittext, nine-patch

[9Patch in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnPxR.png)

[How it looks in API 22 vs API 19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCVav.png)

I have some problems with ninepatch. Im trying to make a border to EditText with bold bottom line. In API22 it works very well, but in API19 it switch white background color with blue.

This is style of my EditText:

```
<style name="EditTextBoxBlue" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ic_border_blue</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/default_padding</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/default_padding</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/default_padding</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/default_padding</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/hintColor</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Plz remove black line that is useless.